# Use view height from other Swift file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So, I understand that to get the height of the view in Swift I can do:

```
viewHeight = view.frame.height
```

But how can I do this outside of that Swift file? I have another swift file which is a class and I need to somehow access the view height there.

I was thinking of so far:

```
viewHeight = MyViewController.view...
```

but it doesn't look like it will work.

Any ideas? All I am looking for is the height of the screen view, not any specific view. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
```

Comment: what is the problem with this.

Comment: Just realised I forgot UIKit

Comment: This means it would get the screen height not a specific view height. The funny thing that @George_E accepted which means that what is he looking for but he didn't mentioned that in the question!

Comment: @AhmadF I'm new, and aren't view heights always the same anyway?

Comment: @George_E if you mean the view controllers main view of course they are! they are the height of the device, which means you don't even have to get the main view of another view controller. But logically I assumed that you are asking for a specific view not the main one, since it's obviously the screen's height.